# Removing series of character in a String

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove all the character in a String after a "?" mark like this:

```
http://xyz.com//static/css/style.css?v=e9b34
```

However I can't just spit it with "?", I need to make sure that the pattern is something `.xyz?any_char_or_symbols`

In other words `extension-?-any_chars_or_symbols`

Anyone can give a hint?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'd find the "css?" substring and and remove from there+3 to the end. It's unlikely that your url will contain question marks before the filename anyway, but that's where you asked about looking.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here or this does it:

```
String s = "http://xyz.com//static/css/style.css?v=e9b34";
int index = s.indexOf('?');
if (index<0)
    return null;
String returned = s.substring(0,index);
if (returned.endsWidth(".xyz");
    return returned;
else
    return null;
```

Comment: This doesn't check for a preceding extension.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström OK, so now it checks that the ? is preceded by ".xyz". Is it what he's looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
return s.replaceFirst("(\\.\\w+\\?).*$", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

First Remove the characters after ? then check for extentions.

```
String url="http://xyz.com//static/css/style.css?v=e9b34"   ;

url=url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));

System.out.print(""+url.matches("^[\\w\\d\\:\\/\\.]+\\.\\w{3}(\\?[\\w\\W]*)?$"));
```

url.matches will check for the extention. I have defined it for 3 words w{3} but you can increase it as w{3,5}. now it will accepts 3 to 5 words extentions. if you want specific formats then use this patteren.

```
url.matches("^[\\w\\d\\:\\/\\.]+\\.(?i)(css|txt|html)?$")
```

Hope it will help.